# Array find min value with user-defined comparison compare function

Tags: php, array

My user defined comparison compare function is defined with an array:

```
$boardkey_to_values=Array(19=>2601248,23=>2601248,39=>2603445,
    43=>2256319,47=>2632006,59=>2603445,63=>2232152,67=>2260713,71=>2632006,...)
```

so `23>19` EDIT:`23=19`, `39>19`, `39<23`,...

I have an array of values `$board_id`, and I want to get the array of all the keys for the minimum values.

Here's my solution, but I don't think it is really intuitive.

```
$min_key=Array(0);
foreach ($board_id as $key => $value) {
if ($boardkey_to_values[$board_id[$min_key[0]]]>$boardkey_to_values[$value])
    $min_key=Array($key);
if ($boardkey_to_values[$board_id[$min_key[0]]]==$boardkey_to_values[$value] && $min_key[0]!=$key)
    $min_key[]=$key;
}
```

Here is an example to show how this should behave:

say `$board_id = [19,23,39,47,71]`

it will look at the values corresponding to this numbers `[2601248,2601248,2603445,2632006,2632006]`

it looks for the smallest value: `2601248`

so the result (`$min_key` should be `[19,23]`)

Comment: Why is 23 > 19 when they both map to the same value? Shouldn't they be equal?

Comment: Yes you're right 23=19, I have edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be *O(n)** where *n* is `count($board_id)`.

```
$mapped = array_map(function ($id) use ($boardkey_to_values) {
    return array($boardkey_to_values[$id], $id);
}, $board_id);
asort($mapped);
list($min_value, $id) = reset($mapped);
$min_ids = array($id);
while (list($value, $id) = next($mapped)) {
    if ($value == $min_value) {
        $min_ids[] = $id;
    }
    else {
        break;
    }
}
```

* ignoring the call to `asort` which is probably *O(n log n)*.

Comment: What exactly does the `use` keyword do after the parameters of an anonymous function ?

Comment: It allows the anonymous function to access the named variable. Without it the function can only access the local variables and arguments it declares.

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing it this way:

```
$min_key = null;
asort($boardkey_to_values);

foreach(array_count_values($boardkey_to_values) as $val) {
  $min_key = array_slice( array_keys($boardkey_to_values), $val );
  break;
}
```

I believe that would accomplish what you're trying to do.

Comment: Your function is very slow compared to mine, because array_slice is slow given the size of the `$boardkey_to_values` (more than 40 000 entries). And it isn't exactly what I meant (cf edit for the example)